# Как настроить приватность в debian через терминал а не через GUI?

Tags: debian

Каждый раз когда я устанавливаю операционную систему я настраиваю приватность в Settings -> Privacy.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне хотелось бы автоматиизировать этот процесс. Я хочу знать можно ли настроить все значения что есть в Settings -> Privacy через терминал а не через GUI?